# Is PyFilesystem's Zip Filesystem indexed? Is it performant for random access reads?

Tags: python, pyfilesystem

Looking at [PyFilesystem's zip filesystem](https://docs.pyfilesystem.org/en/latest/reference/zipfs.html). I want to know if the filesystem is reasonably performant for random access reads with large numbers of files (millions+).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ZipFS is a thin wrapper over Python's zip support. Random access read will be fast.